# I need to add a choice field to sharepoint that has values depending on the current selection

Tags: sharepoint, choicefield

I need to add a choice field to sharepoint that has values depending on the current selection.

Example:

if the current selection is Open then the options have to be 'open, and In progress

```
**Current selection   |  Possible selections**
Open                  |  Open,In progress
In progress           |  In progress,To be communicates,rework
Rework                |  Rework,In Progress
```

...

That way i am forcing the user to follow some specific flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this sort of behavior by editing your list's EditForm.aspx page and adding some JavaScript to the page.

Although I can't seem to find any examples for making dependant drop downs, there are a couple examples of modifying the EditForm to hide fields or make them readonly:

- [Making a field read-only](http://cakriwut.wordpress.com/2006/07/31/how-can-javascripters-create-custom-editform-without-understanding-caml-and-net/)
- [Hiding an entire row on the edit-form](http://www.cleverworkarounds.com/2008/02/07/more-sharepoint-branding-customisation-using-javascript-part-1/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you won't get this field behavior out of the box but you can archive this by implementing your own [CustomFieldType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684919.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look a this:[  www.sharepointsnippets.com/post/2009/01/Cascading-Dropdown---Configuration.aspx ] You need not download any third party software. Otherwise, just google **SharePoint Cascaded/cascading lookup**there are lot of such commercial tools.

Hope this snippet works!

Answer (score 0):

So these are 2 columns out of which one filters the other?

Sounds like a cascading drop down list, there are a few (commercial) solutions out there.
See
http://cascddlistwithfilter.codeplex.com
for a free one.